# SSIS - import flat file to mysql

Tags: csv, ssis

I am new to mysql, and facing with a problem when I try to importing my flat file (~107GB)

> Error: 0xC0202055 at Data Flow Task, Flat File Source [63]: The column delimiter for column "ShipName" was not found.
>
> Error: 0xC0202092 at Data Flow Task, Flat File Source [63]: An error occurred while processing file "F:\AIS資料111(1-12)\shipinformation_202201.csv" on data row 110183.
>
> Error: 0xC0047038 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.
>
> The PrimeOutput method on Flat File Source returned error code 0xC0202092.
>
> The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput().
>
> The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.
>
> There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

Since:

1. column "ShipName" is column 4th/25
2. if row 110183 has problem, how can I remove this row in the Data flow
3. what I should do with the pipeline engine

Thank so much

Comment: _The column delimiter for column "ShipName" was not found._ So that could be a missing `"` or whatever delimiter you are using is missing on that line. Edit the file and find out

Comment: You can send the bad data to another data flow task (to save to generic stage table or something so you dont loose the records).  On the dataflow task after you pull down the arrow for sending to, then you can grab another arrow and it is read for failed records.